# Software to transfer video to dvd in real time - Windows 7 x64

Tags: dvd, video-conversion, video-capture, transcode, camcorder

I have a bunch of Digital 8 tapes that I want to transfer to DVD so I can get rid of this Digital 8 camcorder.

Can someone recommend some software (free or commercial) to help do the job. I've done this before by connecting the camcorder to the computer, saving vid files, and then moving those to the dvd, but I'd like to do it all in one step to save time.

OS:  Windows 7 x64

Comment: You've forgot to mention your OS.

Comment: @iskra - Updated

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I plugged the camera into the computer and [Windows DVD Maker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_DVD_Maker) popped up:

[image: works for me]

Comment: Beautiful isn't it?

Comment: Yes and it has been working well. I'm about halfway through my tape collection with no problems.